# Wildfly 16 : What is benefit of changing XX:MaxMetaspaceSize in Java8?

Tags: java-8, out-of-memory, wildfly, metaspace

I am getting metaspace issue in Wildfly.

Currently XX:MaxMetaspaceSize is 256M. But i am getting following issue multiple times in multiple server groups in different projects (50 projects in total distributed among server groups). And facing following exception daily.

```
failed to define class: OutOfMemoryException: Metaspace
```

Most of posts(stackoverflow and others) suggest it should be 2GB in case of wildfly.

But i have read in various article which suggests that in Java 8 there is no need to increasing Metaspace:

```
In Java 8, the metaspace that holds your classes can expand without limit by default,
```

Could you please resolve this confusion that - if Metaspace is automatically increased and suppose i have set 256 then does it not automatically increase? What benefit i will get at 2G.

Comment: “2G” is an arbitrary number, just like “256M”. I suppose, people are suggesting it, because “2G” is significantly larger than “256M”, not because they knew something specifically. And yes, when you don’t specify an upper limit, there won’t be an upper limit (except your actual machine’s memory).

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html), in Java 8, the class metadata is stored in native memory and by default is unlimited. `MaxMetaspaceSize` puts an upper limit on the native memory that's used for class metadata.

If you also have `UseCompressedOops` and `UseCompressedClassesPointers` enabled, then `MaxMetaspaceSize` sets the upper limit on the sum of both areas of native memory used for class metadata - the area for the compressed class metadata, and the area for all other class metadata.

Also, 2GB sounds a bit high. I would slowly increase and test to be sure you're setting this to an optimal value for your needs.